# I am using react native and when I run my project using npx react-native run-android, I got this error

Tags: android, react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file 'D:\React Native\contacts\android\settings.gradle'
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile settings file 'D:\React Native\contacts\android\settings.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60

**In my settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'contacts'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 0):

i've got this exact same error and for me this is what worked:

1st run: `npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-android`

2nd run: `npm install`